# Kepler Orbits: Equal areas in equal times

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion

I've written some python code to simulate a Kepler orbit.

Every 50 time-steps I draw a radial vector from the centre of the sun to the centre of the earth, as shown below.

However, my understanding should be that after one complete orbit these lines should lie on top of each other.

But if you look at the simulation snapshots you see that there's a slight offset.

Can anyone offer any insight as to why this is and how I could fix the problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What makes you think that after an (arbitrary) 50 time steps the orbit should repeat its position exactly?

Comment: Equal areas in equal times,  so if the time difference is the same then the areas between the radial lines should be the same, and that could only be true if the lines overlap, else you get the situation as in the third picture, where two triangles are not of the same size as the rest? 

I'm almost certainly wrong here though, which is why I'm hoping somebody could explain the flaws in my logic.

Comment: You are choosing an arbitrary time step that might not evenly divide the full period of the orbit though.  For instance, if you take the area of the ellipse, and the time step that you choose sweeps out 9% of that area, after 11 steps, you are 1% short of a full period.  You need to choose a time step that evenly divides the full period of your orbit so that you end up back in the same place after a number of time steps.

Comment: How should anybody know what your problem is if you do not even show your code?

Comment: @СимонТыран: To be fair, we don't diagnose code, so that's really a non-issue.

Comment: tmwilson: does that mean unless the time period properly divides the orbit the equal areas in equal times rule is violated?

Comment: Kyle: there is nothing wrong with the code. It's as simple as can be. It's a conceptual problem.

Comment: No, its still doing equal areas in equal time periods.  The area in this case is a measurable 2D part of the space.  It does *not* mean that the location where you are measuring the area needs to line up each time for an arbitrary time selection.  The measured area should still be equal though.  In your case you can see that when it comes around on the second orbit you are slightly ahead of the previous orbit, but the two lines in the second orbit are *both* slightly ahead.  Measuring the area between those two lines would be the same as the first orbit, even if the location is different.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your radial lines to "line-up" every $n$ lots of  50 time steps, then make sure your time step is the orbital period/50$n$ !

Comment: Does this mean that the equal areas in equal times is only valid if the time-steps divide the orbital period exactly?

Comment: Of course not. It means that you picked a completely arbitrary time and then asked "why doesn't this divide the period exactly?". Well, why would you expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

This is like dividing a clock with 12 marks for each 1 hour into 59 minute intervals. The interval is the same 59 minutes everywhere, but still your 12th interval will not end where the first one started.

To fix this you first have to calculate the duration for 1 total orbit and divide it through a whole number, for example, if the time to draw 1 full orbit is t, make the step size t/n with n being a natural number.